# C - inet_pton() not producing network byte order

Tags: c, sockets, networking, network-programming, endianness

I got confused with the `inet_pton()` function. According to the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_pton.3.html)

> This function converts the character string *src* into a network address structure in the af address family, then copies the network address structure to *dst*.  The af argument must be either AF_INET or AF_INET6. *dst* is written in network byte order.

So the function produces a network byte order value. But I got this code:

```
 struct sockaddr_in a;
 char sip[20];
 inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.168.0.182", (void *)&a.sin_addr);
 inet_ntop(AF_INET, (void *)&a.sin_addr, sip, 20);

 printf("htonl:%08x\n", htonl(a.sin_addr.s_addr));
 printf("inet_pton:%08x\n", a.sin_addr.s_addr);
 printf("inet_ntop:%s\n", sip);
```

output:

```
htonl:c0a800b6
inet_pton:b600a8c0
inet_ntop:192.168.0.182
```

the output of `inet_pton` is `b6.00.a8.c0`, which converts to `182.0.168.192`, and it's also different from the output of `htonl`.

Since `htonl` converts host byte order to network byte order, so if `inet_pton` produces network byte order, I suppose their outputs should be the same? Does it mean that `inet_pton` actually produces host byte order?

if `inet_pton` already produces `network byte order`, why do I need `htonl` to get the right value?

Comment: @alk That's not what I'm trying to do. I was saying that if  ``inet_pton`` stores a ``network byte order`` in ``s_addr``, should ``htonl(s_addr) == s_addr``?

Comment: @27Blend: No because s_addr is just a number. It does not have a tag saying "Network Byte Order" attached to it.

Comment: @ZanLynx ``s_addr`` stores the result of ``inet_pton``, which, according to the man page, writes the value in ``network byte order``. Does this not mean ``s_addr`` is written in ``network byte order``?

Comment: @27Blend It looks like it IS in network byte order to me. In your print statements when you print the result of inet_pton it comes out backwards. Probably because you compiled and ran that on an x86 processor, which is NOT in network byte order so it reverses it.

Comment: @27Blend You also seem to be confused as to what the ntohl and htonl macros do. On Intel CPUs both of them do exactly the same thing: reverse the byte order. On a PowerPC in big endian mode, or a SPARC, those macros do absolutely nothing. On a PDP-11, if you had one, they have to do different things because a PDP-11 is middle-endian which is a whacked out thing where 32-bit words are reversed 16 bits at a time.

Comment: `printf("inet_pton:%08x\n", a.sin_addr.s_addr);` will print the 32 bit integer you give it in host endian, which will look reversed compared to network endian. inet_pton does store the bytes in network endian, but your printf() statement is tricking you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `inet_pton` puts the address bytes into the destination buffer in network order. Let's go through an example to see what happens. Using your address of "192.168.0.182", `inet_pton` produces these four bytes:

```
c0   a8  00  b6    (hex)
192  168 0   182   (dec)
```

That *is* network byte order. When you then call `htonl` (which is not actually correct -- you should be calling `ntohl` to convert *from* network order to host order but as @ZanLynx pointed out, the two functions are identical on x86), you re-order the bytes to:

```
b6 00 a8 c0
```

But then you pass that form to `printf` with `%x` as the format. That tells `printf` to interpret the four bytes as a single 32-bit integer, but x86 is a little endian machine, so when it loads the four bytes as an integer, the `b6` is the lowest order byte and the `c0` is the highest, which produces what you saw:

```
htonl:c0a800b6
```

So, in general, if you have an IPv4 address in network form, and you want to quickly display it (for debugging or whatever) in an order that "makes sense" to you (as a programmer) you would use:

```
printf("%x\n", ntohl(a.sin_addr.s_addr));
```

You could also display the single bytes as they reside in network order (which is really the exact same thing but may be easier to wrap your head around), just use an `unsigned char *` (or equivalently `uint8_t *` from `<stdint.h>`) to print the individual bytes:

```
uint8_t *ipp = (void *)&a.sin_addr.s_addr;
printf("%02x %02x %02x %02x\n", ipp[0], ipp[1], ipp[2], ipp[3]);
```

(You need to use an unsigned type here to avoid sign extension. In the above statement, each char will be promoted to an `int` in the call to `printf`. If you have a signed `char` containing, say, 0xc0, it will typically be *sign-extended* into a 32-bit `int`: 0xffffffc0. As an alternative, you can use the format specification `"%02hhx"` which explicitly tells `printf` that you are really passing it a `char`; then it will only look at the lowest order byte of each promoted `int`.)